# Eigenvalue of the 'norm' matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-norms

A week ago, I asked a question about the matrix composed with absolute difference of distinct number must have exactly only one positive eigenvalue. But I have no idea how to prove it with 'norm' matrix $A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}$, where
$$
a_{ij}=\|\xi_{i}-\xi_{j}\|_2.
$$
Here $\xi_i\in\mathbb{R}^m$ are distinct vector and $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the Euclidean norm. Also I have verified it with `MATLAB` for $n=20$ and $m=5$, but the method used for $m=1$ failed. Any advice is welcome!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem

Comment: @TheoBendit I don't see how Perron-Frobenius is relevant here.  The question is about unique positive eigenvalue, not eigenvector.  Indeed P-F says nothing about whether there are other positive eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This matrix is known and is called a distance matrix see e.g. in Wikipedia section [Distance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_matrix). The fact that such matrices have exactly one positive eigenvalue is discussed, for example, in the paper by E. Bogomolny et al.
[Distance matrices and isometric embeddings](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.2063.pdf).

Distance matrices were also discussed in MSE, e.g., [Distance matrix properties](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3149878/distance-matrix-properties)